# Is it possible to change method function handlers in MATLAB classdef

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to use MATLAB OOP. I would like to change the class method handler in the class constructor.
For example, I have a class `test` where a class method uses one of methods depending on the variable`number` in class properties:

```
mytest = test(2);
mytest.somemethod();

classdef test < handle
  properties
    number
  end
  methods        
    function obj = test(number)
      obj.number = number;
    end
    function obj = somemethod(obj)
      switch obj.number
        case 1
          obj.somemethod1();
        case 2
          obj.somemethod2();
        case 3
          obj.somemethod3();
      end
    end
    function obj = somemethod1(obj)
      fprintf('1')
    end
    function obj = somemethod2(obj)
      fprintf('2')
    end
    function obj = somemethod3(obj)
      fprintf('3')
    end
  end
end
```

Here the `switch` operator is used whenever `test.somemethod()` is called. Can I use `switch` once only at the time of initialization in the class constructor (ie change the method handler) as follows:

```
classdef test < handle
  properties
    number
    somemethod %<--
  end
  methods
    % function obj = somemethod(obj,number) % my mistake: I meant the constructor
    function obj = test(number)
      obj.number = number;
      switch number
        case 1
          obj.somemethod = @(obj) obj.somemethod1(obj);
        case 2
          obj.somemethod = @(obj) obj.somemethod2(obj);
        case 3
          obj.somemethod = @(obj) obj.somemethod3(obj);
      end
    end
    function obj = somemethod1(obj)
      fprintf('1')
    end
    function obj = somemethod2(obj)
      fprintf('2')
    end
    function obj = somemethod3(obj)
      fprintf('3')
    end
  end
end
```

This second implementation of the `test` class does not work.
For `S = test(2); S.somemethod()`, there is an error: 
*Error using test>@(obj)obj.somemethod2(obj) (line ...)
Not enough input arguments.*
What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can't have `somemethod` as a method *and* a property. You can get rid of the method and assign a function handle to the property in your constructor.

```
function self = test(number)
    self.number = number;
    switch self.number
        case 1
            self.somemethod = @(obj)somemethod1(obj)
    %....
    end
end
```

Also, your current anonymous functions you've passed *two* copies of the object to the method:

1. `obj.method` implicitly passes `obj` as the first input
2. `obj.method(obj)` passes a second copy of `obj` as the second input

You want to update your object handles to something like the following which will pass a single copy of `obj` to the method.

```
obj.somemethod = @obj.somemethod3
```

Also, when using your class, you'll have to execute `somemethod` using dot notation since it's a property and not a "real" method

```
S = test()
S.somemethod()
```

Comment: About the same name in properties and methods it is my typemistake (I meant initialization in the constructor). But 'S = test(2); S.somemethod()' generates the error: "Error using test>@(obj)obj.somemethod2(obj) Not enough input arguments."

Comment: @AlexanderKorovin sorry I mistyped that. Should be working now

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I found that this implementation (`obj.somemethod = @ obj.somemethod3`) is about two times slower than when using `switch`!